# A question on perturbed ODE (bender and orszag)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

This is from example 2 of chapter seven, consider the IVP

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
y''=f(x)y,
y(0)=1,
y'(0)=1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
we then make a perturbation expansion $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\epsilon^ny_n(x)$

I get \begin{equation}
f(x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\epsilon^{n+1}y_n(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\epsilon^ny''_n(x)
\end{equation}

I don't see how we deduce both \begin{equation}
f(x)y_{n-1}(x)=y''_n(x)
\end{equation}

and the solution
\begin{equation}
y_n=\int_{0}^{x}dt\int_{0}^{t}dsf(s)y_{n-1}(s) 
\end{equation}

for all $n\geq 1$
Sorry if I'm asking to be spoon fed here but I feel like I am being blind to something very simple...

Comment: You don't. For that to be true you would need to have $ϵ$ as a factor on the right side of the original equation. The iteration itself is a variant of the Picard iteration, meaning under mild assumptions $y_n$ will converge to the solution of the IVP. // Can you give more information to the source of this claim?

Comment: Bender and Orszag advanced mathematical methods page 321-322, sorry I didn't include that before we use the peturbation expansion we first let $y''=\epsilon f(x)y(x)$